# Devc++ - 'IFileOperation' undeclared (C++)

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I would like to add objects `IFileOperation` and `IShellItem`, but I can not fill in any way the source and gives me back:

```
IFileOperation - undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I'm using Dev-C++ with the parameters of the linker: `-luuid -lole32`

I suppose I must add other header but every google search is not successful.
Do you have any idea?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgument, int nFunsterStil)
{
    HRESULT     hr;
    IShellLink* pISL;

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink,         // CLSID of coclass
                          NULL,                    // not used - aggregation
                          CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,    // type of server
                          IID_IShellLink,          // IID of interface
                          (void**) &pISL);         // Pointer to our interface pointer

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        pISL->Release();
    }
    else
    {
        // Couldn't create the COM object.  hr holds the error code.
    }

    CoUninitialize();
}
```

Comment: The interface definitions for `IFileOperation` and `IShellItem` are *both* in `<Shobjidl.h>` per the [documentation from MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That documentation is the **first hit** from simply googling *either* `IShellItem` or `IFileOperation`, and brings into suspect the claim of "...every google search is not successful.", or at the very least, whatever term you were searching for.

Comment: Including #include<Shobjidl.h> return this error:"Shobjidl.h: No such file or directory. " So the problem remains, how can I proceed?

Comment: Are you compiling using a Windows Vista or later compatible SDK ? If not, you won't find that file (also noted in the same document). What SDK version are you using, and what platform are you targeting? Unless DevC++ has at-least Windows Vista/Server2008 SDK compliance, it isn't going to work, and you may be relegated to using the legacy SHFileOperation subsystem instead. (yuck)

Comment: I'm compiling with Windows 7 SP1

Comment: Is that the OS you're running, or the **SDK** that DevC++ is **using** ? There is a difference. The former runs your tools; the former is what your tools *use* when building your program. Or does it use `mingw`, and if so, is *it* up to at least Windows Vista or later features?

Comment: With orwelldevcpp everything seems solved, not more problems syntax, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to link your program to `Shell32.lib` 
try going to you program settings, then find the linker and add `-lShell32.lib` to it and save.

anyway, Dev-C++ is a nice compilerwhen you start programing and you want to write some code , compile it and run it. but this IDE is very ancient and unefficient , consider to move to Visual studio if you're using windows.

Comment: It is a missing definition at compile-time; not a link-time missing reference (though eventually, he's going to need to link shell32.lib regardless).